# optimize insert operation in MySQL (InnoDB)

Tags: python, mysql

I have this table:

```
create table tab3(
id                              int not null auto_increment,
phrase                          text,
link_1                          int,
link_2                          int,
primary key (id),
foreign key (link_1) references tab1 (id),
foreign key (link_2) references tab2 (id));
```

I am inserting around 400k rows into this table with Python.
this is the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO tab3(phrase, link_1, link_2)
    VALUES(
        %s,
        (select id from tab1 where tab1.col1 = %s),
        (select id from tab2 where tab2.col2 = %s));
```

I have an index on both tables tab1.col1 and tab2.col2. but the insertion is taking a long time around 5mins/1000 row

I've tried many different techniques [from the official docs of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20following,separate%20single%2Drow%20INSERT%20statements.) such as:

- using cursor.execute(stmt,param)
- using cursor.executemany(stmt, param**s**)
- multiple processes ( billiard https://pypi.org/project/billiard/ )
- blocking the commit until all chunk of data is inserted and then commit changes
- encapsulating the insert stmt inside one transaction ( with **START TRANSACTION** )

But None of the above gave a good improvement.

Comment: You've set up your foreign key on tab3.link1 to reference tab1.id. But then you use a SELECT statement to get the id of the row which has the same link1 as the value you provide. Why not simplify this, and make link1 the primary key of tab1, and set up tab3.link1 as a foreign key of tab1.link1? Would make your insertion process simpler and likely faster.

Comment: @NickODell phrase column is text, which is not really suitable to be a primary key

Comment: But the link_1 column is an int, no?

Comment: Which database do you use (MariaDB != MySQL) and which Python connector?

Comment: @NickODell, thanks it was a typo I fix it ... tab3.link_1 refrence tab1.id and ta3.link_2 reference tab2.id

Comment: Hi @GeorgRichter ! I am using MySQL and for the python connector I am actually using airflow mysqlhook which itself uses mysqlclient  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/stable/_api/airflow/providers/mysql/hooks/mysql/index.html#module-airflow.providers.mysql.hooks.mysql  


https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/stable/index.html#requirements

Comment: What is the average size of `phrase` and how many records do you try to insert via executemany() ?

Comment: @GeorgRichter the max size of phrase is around 6k characters and the number of records via execute many is around 65k

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/331074/optimize-insert-operation-in-mysql-innodb

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL doesn't support native batch execution MySQL Connector/Python tries to rewrite the statement to a multiple value statement, e.g.

```
data= [(1,),(2,),(3,), ...(1000,)]
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO t1 (a) VALUES(%s)", data)
```

will produce the statement:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a) VALUES (1),(2),(3),...(1000)
```

With a subselect the statement will look like:

```
INSERT INTO tab3(phrase, link_1, link_2)
VALUES("foo1", (select id from tab1 where tab1.col1 = int1_1),
    (select id from tab2 where tab2.col2 = int2_1)),
VALUES("foo2", (select id from tab1 where tab1.col1 = int1_2),
    (select id from tab2 where tab2.col2 = int2_2)),
...
VALUES("foo1000", (select id from tab1 where tab1.col1 = int1_1000),
     (select id from tab2 where tab2.col2 = int2_1000)),
```

If you will run this statement with `EXPLAIN` you will notice, that MySQL must execute 2000 subqueries, which is far away from optimal.

So instead create a temporary table and fill your data into temporary table:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lookup(phrase varchar(6000), col1 int unsigned, col2 int unsigned, unique index(col1), unique index(col2))")
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO lookup VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", data);
```

Depending on the memory on the server you should also consider to use memory storage engine. Afterwards just insert the data from the temporary table:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tab3 SELECT lookup.phrase, lookup.col1, lookup.col2 from lookup, tab1, tab2 where lookup.col2=tab2.col1 and lookup.col1=tab1.col1")
```

Some comments about your table definition:

- if the maximum size of phrase is 6000, then better use VARCHAR instead of TEXT.
- auto_increment columns should be defined as UNSIGNED.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
the insert statement in tab3 involves joining 3 tables which will introduce new delay